# how to run scrapy in a Django view and alert Django when the spider is finished?

Tags: django, scrapy

I am trying to start a scrape spider from a Django view and have a method of knowing when the spider is finished.

I can run the spider successfully by disabling signals in the crawler process. Like in the code below. Because the scrapy signals need to run in the main thread to function.

But the only way I am currently aware of knowing when the spider has finished is using the spider_closed signal. Is there another way alert Django when the spider is finished or a method to make sure the spider and the signals run in the main thread?

```
class PosmoScraperView(APIView):
    # Authentication classes
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    # Requires user authenticate to access
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get user input from json
        serializer = StartURLSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # Get url from json post request
            start_url = serializer.validated_data['url']

            # Get spider settings
            process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

            # Run the Scrapy spider
            process.crawl(BaseSpiderSpider, start_url=start_url)
            process.start(stop_after_crawl=True, install_signal_handlers=False)


            return Response({'status': 'request received'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```